# XPATH All Selectors Return Null

Tags: javascript, xpath, null, rendering

I am wanting to know if it is possible to pull Xpath on the following website page(s)

https://directories.apps.realtor/memberDetail/?personId=4165309&officeStreetCountry=US&memberLastName=BROWN

I keep getting the error "All Selectors Return Null".  I would like to retrieve: NAME, BUSINESS EMAIL, OFFICE, OFFICE WE PAGE, OFFICE ADDRESS and OFFICE PHONE if possible. Thanks in advance

I tried to use an Xpath Add-On from Google Sheets. I've successfully used the program with other sites but for some reason I can't get it to work on this particular site.

Comment: The page seems to add the values dynamically, which makes it so that you cannot scrap them by simply loading the HTML view. You need something like Selenium instead.